# safely handle huge numbers in python extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-extensions

Since Python 3 there's no upper limit on the size of an int. I'd like to deal with huge ints of 150+ decimal digits.

This is far larger than a `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be, so I don't think I can rely on `PyLong_AsLongLong` and manipulate that.

How can I perform mathematical operations on such large ints that get passed to my C extension's methods?

Comment: Hmm... you [just built](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/257264/230375) ints with 1000000+ digits, and now you call 150+ digits "huge"? :-P

Comment: @Manuel lmao, good to see you. I just pulled a random result from that actually, it was one of the smaller lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just handle them *as* Python ints, with Python arithmetic operations like [`PyNumber_Add`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Add) and [`PyNumber_Multiply`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Multiply). Don't try to convert to a machine integer.

Now, if you were hoping to gain any speed advantage by doing this in C, well, that's not going to happen. If you want to optimize large integer operations, try a more efficient bignum library, like [gmpy2](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/). Make sure your algorithm is efficient, too - that `_reverseBits` thing from your code review question is extremely inefficient regardless of the integer implementation used.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the existence of all the PyNumber stuff.

Comment: I'd say the algorithmic efficiency of their `_reverseBits` isn't that bad, given that they apparently only use it on tiny numbers.

Comment: @Manuel: Yeah, on closer look, it looks like how they handle `bitstream` is a bigger issue. This algorithm really needs to work in terms of a bit sequence rather than bignums.